# Why can't Rust infer an appropriate lifetime for my trait method?

Tags: rust

I've got a function `take_head` that takes two parameters: a slice, and the number of items in the "head" of the slice (the "head" being the first `n` items, and the "tail" being everything after the head). It splits the slice into two parts: the `head`, which it returns, and the `tail`, which it sets the parameter to. Here's the `main` function showing how it's used:

```
fn main() {
    let mut strings = &mut ["a", "b", "c"][..];
    println!("original: {:?}", strings);

    // head should ["a"], and strings should be set to the tail (["b", "c"]).
    let head = take_head(&mut strings, 1);

    println!("head: {:?}", head);    // Should print ["a"].
    println!("tail: {:?}", strings); // Should print ["b", "c"].
}
```

If I implement `take_head` like so:

```
fn take_head<'a>(strings: &mut &'a mut [&'a str], n: usize) -> &'a mut [&'a str] {
    let value = std::mem::replace(strings, &mut []);
    let (head, tail) = value.split_at_mut(n);
    *strings = tail;

    println!("returning head: {:?}", head);
    head
}
```

[it works correctly](http://is.gd/fpF0DI) and outputs:

> ```
> original: ["a", "b", "c"]
> returning head: ["a"]
> head: ["a"]
> tail: ["b", "c"]
> ```

However, if I implement `take_head` like this:

```
// Make a convenient trait for slices.
pub trait TakeFrontMut<T> {
    fn take_front_mut(&mut self, n: usize) -> &mut [T];
}

impl<'a, T> TakeFrontMut <T> for &'a mut [T] {
    fn take_front_mut(&mut self, n: usize) -> &mut [T] {
        // It's the same code as before, just in a trait method.
        let value = std::mem::replace(self, &mut []);
        let (head, tail) = value.split_at_mut(n);
        *self = tail;
        return head;
    }
}

fn take_head<'a>(strings: &mut &'a mut [&'a str], n: usize) -> &'a mut [&'a str] {
    let head = strings.take_front_mut(n);
    println!("returning head: {:?}", head);
    head
}
```

[It produces an error](http://is.gd/J5CzfX):

> ```
> <anon>:15:24: 15:41 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
> <anon>:15     let head = strings.take_front_mut(n);
>                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> <anon>:14:1: 18:2 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn take_head<'a>(strings: &'a mut &'a mut [&'a str], n: usize)
>  -> &'a mut [&'a str]
> <anon>:14 fn take_head<'a>(strings: &mut &'a mut [&'a str], n: usize) -> &'a mut [&'a str] {
> <anon>:15     let head = strings.take_front_mut(n);
> <anon>:16     println!("returning head: {:?}", head);
> <anon>:17     head
> <anon>:18 }
> ```

**Question**: Why does the second version produce an error? What's so different that the parser can't determine the appropriate lifetime? I don't understand why it's failing, and I'm not sure what these conflicting requirements are.

<sub>Yes, the `take_head` function is dumb, but it's the simplest MVCE I could make that still captures the same issue as my real code.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `take_front_mut` doesn't specify the correct lifetime for the return value. It should be `&'a mut [T]`, because that's the lifetime of the slice you split. This also requires you to make a change on the trait itself.

```
pub trait TakeFrontMut<'a, T> {
    fn take_front_mut(&mut self, n: usize) -> &'a mut [T];
}

impl<'a, T> TakeFrontMut<'a, T> for &'a mut [T] {
    fn take_front_mut(&mut self, n: usize) -> &'a mut [T] {
        let value = std::mem::replace(self, &mut []);
        let (head, tail) = value.split_at_mut(n);
        *self = tail;
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, awesome! I tried making the trait's method signature `fn take_front_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, n: usize) -> &'a mut [T];`, which didn't work (and I'm not sure why... it seems like it effectively means the same thing as what you wrote, but apparently there must be some difference between the two that I'm unaware of).

Comment: The lifetime of the output slice must be the lifetime of the input slice, not the lifetime of the *pointer* to the input slice! The lifetime on mutable references is invariant, and the lifetime of the pointer will generally be shorter than the lifetime of the slice.